# What is the grammatical topic of this shortening technique?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, complements, omissibility, whiz-deletion, cloze-test

Extracted from an English cloze test:

> .....these virtual selves exist in the same online spaces that many people use every day. And this is a new and unfamiliar phenomenon that some people might find___________ -- previously dead people were not present in this way.

1. trouble
2. troubled
3. troubling
4. be troubled
5. to trouble

The answer is 3 because the key said *find troubling* stands for *find it to be troubling*, but I don't understand why it stands for that. I want to know what grammatical topic is related to this sentence.

Comment: _Find troubling_ is equivalent to _find to be troubling_ here – not _find it to be troubling_, which would not be a grammatical substitution.

Comment: Are you familiar with the idiom:to find something (funny, amusing, interesting, unusual, etc. etc.)?

Comment: Hello, อริศรา จรูญธรรม. Can you recheck the punctuation used in the cloze test question that you ask about and see whether there is a comma after "previously" in the original? As it happens, "previously, dead people" has a very different meaning from "previously dead people."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's a lot happening here.

Here is a shorter version of the sentence in question:

> This is a phenomenon **that some people might find troubling**.

The bold part is a [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses). We can re-write this sentence without the relative clause, like this:

> Some people might find **this phenomenon troubling**.

In this new sentence, the word "troubling" is an adjective, and the bold part ("this phenomenon troubling") is a [small clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_clause). The phrase "to find this phenomenon troubling" means "to feel that this phenomenon is troubling." So we can re-write this sentence again, like this:

> Some people might feel that this phenomenon is troubling.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "grammatical topic". The test question as I see it is simply to choose the grammatically correct way of filling in the blank. Choice 3 is the only one that does so in context. Another possibility that could fit is "to be troubling", but that was not a provided choice.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, RichF.  I think what OP is asking is, where can one read more about the shortening technique mentioned in the answer key's explanation?

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about the break after the answer word, this is probably meant to be a dash.

See: [Usages of a dash vs Hyphen](https://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-dash.htm)

Not to be mistaken for a hypen, this question finishes with a pause and afterthought. The test print probably didn't accept dash characters, instead only hyphens using basic Ascii.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357622/whats-the-ascii-character-code-for Explains this very well